# Modified Bessel functions: definition and image

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

$I_n(x)$ and $K_n(x)$ are respectively the modified Bessel function of the first and the second kind. They can be used to solve the [modified Bessel differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselDifferentialEquation.html).

It seems that they can be defined in multiple ways. One way is:

$$I_n(x) = -i^n J_n(ix) = i^{-n} J_n(ix) \label{a} \tag{1}$$

(where $J_n$ is the [Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html)) and

$$K_n(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} i^{n + 1} H_n^{(1)}(ix) \label{b} \tag{2}$$

(where $H_n^{(1)}$ is the [Hankel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HankelFunctionoftheFirstKind.html)). $x$ is a real variable.

1. Are $I_n(x)$ and $K_n(x)$ real functions? In other words: given the real variable $x$, are $I_n(x)$ and $K_n(x)$ **always** real numbers?
2. If yes, how to prove it? The imaginary unit $i$ is in both $\ref{a}$ and $\ref{b}$ and it is seems counterintuitive that the final result is real.

---

Side note: any book reference, or link, with an exhaustive definition of these functions is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1**.
Yes: if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, they are always real functions. In fact, they have been obtained *ad hoc* to formulate a general, real solution for the [modified Bessel differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselDifferentialEquation.html):

$$f(x) = AI_{\nu}(x) + BK_{\nu}(x)$$

It is real, if $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$.

**2**.
The [modified Bessel differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselDifferentialEquation.html) is linear: if $J_{\nu}(ix)$ is a solution, $CJ_{\nu}(ix)$, $C \in \mathbb{C}$ is a solution, too. Observing the [series definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1) of $J_{\nu}(ix)$, the arbitrary choice $C = i^{-\nu}$ will generate a real function of the variable $x$ only: $I_{\nu}(x) = i^{-\nu} J_{\nu}(ix)$ is the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1). The [modified Bessel function of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) $K_{\nu}(x)$ is **also** defined as

$$K_{\nu}(x) = \pi \frac{\left[ I_{-\nu}(x) - I_{\nu} (x) \right]}{2 \sin (\nu \pi)}$$

for $\nu \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ , and as the limit of the above expression for $\nu \to n \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $\nu$ is real, being $I_{\nu}(x)$ and $I_{-\nu}(x)$ real functions, $K_{\nu}(x)$ will be real, too.